# How to display a cell value MySql Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I need to display value from db in my view file.

For example in my `view/index.php` (I need to do it in view)

```
<?= 
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT adress FROM  comp  WHERE name = in_tk")->execute(); 
?>
```

So it return `0` or `1`. `0` if returns `0` row. `1` or more if returns `1` or more row. But I need to display value of a row. 
For example in db: `adress = 205`. That sql will display `1`.

What yii2 method I need to do to display value of the cell?

Comment: would you pls show your code and elaborate more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use queryAll instead execute to get all rows.

```
<?= 
    $rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT adress FROM  comp  WHERE name = in_tk")->queryAll(); 
?>
```

Comment: Use queryOne() to get the first and queryScalar() to get the value

Comment: Thank you so much! `queryScalar()` is solution. I will study more deeply yii2 Classes.